# How can I determine which parameters are allowed in a HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an assessment to make, but I am not sure whether or not this question is using the wrong terms? Because I feel like it should ask me which attributes are allowed, or am I just clueless?

**Here is the literal translation of the question:**

In Laravel Blade you see the following code:

```
 <x-form name="myform" id="1"></x-form>
```

How do you determine which other parameters are allowed in this HTML tag?

I was thinking a querySelector can be useful here, but I am not sure.

Comment: Why do you think this has something to do with JavaScript. Better tag this with `laravel-blade`

Comment: This is neither HTML nor is it Javascript.

Comment: I thought they gave up just a random name for a HTML tag, but yeah, appearantly these are custom Laravel components. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

As this is a Laravel component basically you are allowed unlimited attributes in components because it totally depends on your logic. The number of attributes you define in your component class can be used here. You can get more information on Laravel documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#components

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a rookie question. Thanks for the information anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The trick in this question is that it tests your knowledge about [Blade Components](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#components). So the valid answer will be:
<x-form> is custom Blade Component, so i will go into default components directory (which is App\View\Components) and see the definition of the component with all valid attributes.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the information, well I did notice the custom tag, but the penny just didn't drop back when I wrote this thread.